# Lucene GermanAnalyzer treats different inputs differently

Tags: character-encoding, lucene

I have a problem with GermanAnalyzer. I need it just to search for names. 
Let's say I have in my table documents {"Muller","Mueller","Müller"}.
Now if I use

```
    Analyzer analyzer = new GermanAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_43);
    String querystr = "Muller~0.1"
    Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_43, "Name", analyzer).parse(querystr);
```

it expectedky returns all of the documents. But when I try

```
    String querystr = "Müller~0.1"
```

or

```
    String querystr = "Mueller~0.1"
```

it doesn't return anything. I don't know if I'm missing something, or if it's a bug. I don't think that encoding is the problem, because in search for "Mueller" there are just normal characters in use. Any comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by normalizing the searched String with `GermanNormalizationFilter(String string)`.

```
    public static List<String> tokenizeString(String string) throws IOException {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        Tokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer(version, new StringReader(string));
        TokenStream stream = new StandardFilter(version, source);
        stream = new GermanNormalizationFilter(stream);
        CharTermAttribute cattr = stream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        stream.reset();
        while (stream.incrementToken()) {
            result.add(cattr.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }
```